# Bounding box for PostGIS table

Tags: postgis, sql, bbox

Is there an easy way to get the bounding box for an entire table in PostGIS?

Answer (score 40):

[ST_Extent](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Extent.html) should do the trick.

> ST_Extent — an aggregate function that returns the bounding box that bounds rows of geometries.

Applied like this:

```
SELECT ST_Extent(the_geom) as table_extent FROM your_table;
```

Answer (score 24):

As [@underdark answered](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/14951/115), [ST_Extent](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Extent.html) will do the job, but keep in mind that it does not return a geometry but a `box2d`. If you need a geometry type you should use something like

```
SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Extent(the_geom), THE_SRID) as table_extent FROM your_table;
```

Also, if what you need is get the bounding box of each of the rows you can also use `ST_Extent` and a *fake* `GROUP BY` like this:

```
SELECT ST_SetSRID(ST_Extent(the_geom),THE_SRID) as table_extent FROM your_table GROUP BY gid;
```

Assuming that gid is the primary key of the table

But [ST_Envelope](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_Envelope.html) will do a better job as @bugmenot123 stated in the comments

```
SELECT ST_Envelope(geom) FROM your_table ;
```

Comment: If you need a bounding box for each row with no aggregation, just use `ST_Envelope`! That's not what was asked for though.

Comment: You are right about st_envelope i update the answer. About the "not asked for", sometimes a try to give related answers because for people that not speak English well (like me) is difficult to choose the correct search text to find an answer. Probably i fell in this question searching an answer for the second topic.

Answer (score 9):

Another possibility is to use the `ST_Envelope` function, which returns a geometry with SRID,

> ST_Envelope — Returns a geometry representing the bounding box of the
>   supplied geometry

, along with the aggregate function `ST_Union` to obtain the union of all geometries (or the union of their respective envelopes) as follows:

```
SELECT ST_Envelope(ST_Union(geom)) AS table_extent FROM your_table
```

or

```
SELECT ST_Envelope(ST_Union(ST_Envelope(geom))) AS table_extent FROM your_table
```

The second option should be faster as it simplifies the union operation by using the envelopes of individual geometries.

see [Source](http://postgis.17.x6.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=print_post&node=5002609).

Comment: The ST_Extent approach is *magnitudes* faster as it can operate purely on numbers and does not have to do any complex geometric calculations. Avoid ST_Union whenever you can.

Answer (score 9):

Not enforcing any spatial aggregation should be way quicker:

```
select
  min(ST_XMin(geom)) as _left,
  min(ST_YMin(geom)) as _bottom,
  max(ST_XMax(geom)) as _right,
  max(ST_YMax(geom)) as _top
from x
```

Comment: ST_Extent also does not have to do anything spatial. It is 2-3 times faster than your approach for my data (~400k polygons). Probably because it can do it all in one go, while your approach has to look at several aspects of each geom and then aggregate in the end.