# MySQL: Query the envelope (mbr, extents) of a spatial table?

Tags: mysql-spatial

[this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14948/bounding-box-for-postgis-table) provides a solution to get the [evelope](https://web.archive.org/web/20150520110803/http://dev.mysql.com:80/doc/refman/4.1/en/general-geometry-property-functions.html#function_envelope) (aka: mbr, aka: extents) of a spatial table in PostGIS, but I'm having trouble doing the same in MySQL.

The [ogr MySQL driver](https://gdal.org/ogr/drv_mysql.html) does this, and a solution is noted [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20140524042852/http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/georuby-devel/2006-May/000011.html) on a Ruby forum (circa 2006), but surely this doesn't require external programming? Does anyone have a clean SQL recipe for this case?

---

**[Answer]**

After getting pointed in the right direction by @GIS-Jonathan, the working query ends up looking like what follows. *CAVEAT: You may not need to change the `group_concat_max_len` value for a small table, but large tables with many features may need the larger `group_concat_max_len` buffer. It seems safe to me to just increase this value in the session as part of the solution.*

```
# increase group_concat_max_len to be safe

SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 104448;

# air8 is my geodata table
# shape is the geometry column

SELECT 
  asText(
    Envelope(
      GeomFromText(
        Concat(Concat("geometrycollection(", Group_Concat(asText(shape))),")")
      )
    )
  ) 
  AS extent FROM air8;
```

**[Concluding Remark]**

I was curious how well this would scale against larger tables and found that it starts to break down around some upper limit I don't have the time to identify.

For a table with 60864 features, I had to use `SET SESSION group_concat_max_len = 10444800;`, then it worked (that's up to about 10MB). However, for a table with 242439 features, I tried 104448000 (about 100MB), then 1044480000 (about 1GB), then most rediculously 10444800000 (about 10GB). At that point I quit caring if it would eventually work because surely that violates sensible practice!

**Anyway here is the take-home message: If you run this on a large dataset and it returns `null`, you may very well be hitting the upper limit.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [this thread](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?23,249284,249284#msg-249284) may answer your question. It doesn't look like the simplest solution, but it may give you a starting point.

Comment: Hey thanks, that grab looks good. I'll give it a shot and return to accept assuming it's on the money. /E

Comment: Yes that worked great. I'll update the qustion to include the query I used. Thanks for the fast help.