# How to identify upper left point from column of points?

Tags: postgis, geometry, extents

I have a column that contains points (all they make one tile) and I need to extract the upper left point based on point coordinates.

Is there any built-in function in PostGIS to find?

Otherwise, I am thinking to get the first Xmin and Ymax manually by sorting.

[image]

Comment: once you have the extent as shown in https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/14948/bounding-box-for-postgis-table the individual corners are easy

Comment: But the corners of the extent may not be points in the underlying dataset.  I think a simple SQL sort is the way to go here.

Comment: What if there is one slightly to the right but more to the north, which is the upper left?

Comment: You have to define whether North or West has priority.